# nodejs hello world example - symbol lookup error

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js

**UPDATE -- LINUX FEDORA 15**

Following an example from:

http://simonwillison.net/2009/Nov/23/node/

**My code:**

```
var util = require('util'),
    http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.sendHeader(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
  res.sendBody('<h1>Hello World</h1>');
  res.finish();
}).listen(8080);

util.puts('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080');
```

**Produces the following error:**

```
[abu@Beelzebub node_projects]$ nodejs helloworld.js
Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080
nodejs: symbol lookup error: nodejs: undefined symbol: _ZN2v82V816IdleNotificationEv
```

Comment: my initial install was with the yum package manager.  I believe I had to perform some update to the repository (or reference an alternate one) to install node.js

Comment: The problem has been resolved though.  I removed an existing node application ( had something to do with radios? ); then downloaded and installed the rpm nodejs-0.6.15-1 (Apr 11) from http://nodejs.tchol.org/  using the standard make install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is 2009 tutorial and old api. You should do it like this

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.end("Hello World\n");
});
server.listen(8000);
console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/");
```

Your tutorial is old :) switch to this ->

http://howtonode.org/hello-node

Answer (score 0):

To execute a node.js application, call it using node, not nodejs.

```
node helloworld.js
```

The particular error seems similar to a V8 build mismatch problem that was in Node 0.6.15. Have you tried using a newer (or rolling back to an older) version of Node?

Comment: there was another node (not related to JS in any way) application; I'm assuming that is why node.js installed as nodejs to avoid the conflict...

Comment: It seems to have come down to some dependency issue... I had initially installed with the yum package manager; this method doesn't seem to be as reliable as downloading the file and performing the standard make install.

Answer (score 0):

To **perform node.js installation on Fedora Linux** download and install the standalone rpm (http://nodejs.tchol.org/stable/f16/SRPMS/repoview/nodejs.html) and perform install as follows:

1. Remove any existing node and nodejs applications using your package manager
2. Install node.js from standalone rpm

   rpm –ivh 
   ./configure
   make
   make install

Attempting to use a package manager may lead to dependency issues as described on the following site:

http://nodejs.tchol.org/