# Node.js symbol lookup error on Fedora 16

Tags: node.js, installation, fedora

I installed Node.JS on Fedora 16, but when i'm started daemon it's throw error:

```
sdfnode: symbol lookup error: node: undefined symbol: _ZN2v82V816IdleNotificationEv
```

To solve the problem I reinstalled from this repository: http://nodejs.tchol.org/, it did not help. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I really suggest following [this recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10375827/1229023) when installing node.js on Fedora.

Comment: I don't understand what do this command: `rpm –ivh ./configure make make install`. How I can install from standalone rpm?

Comment: You can try to do `sudo yum localinstall /path/to/rpm`, as mentioned [here](http://nodejs.tchol.org/).

Comment: But I somehow thought [rpm](http://www.cyberciti.biz/howto/question/linux/linux-rpm-cheat-sheet.php) is a core package in Fedora... Sorry, don't have much experience working with it, prefer the Debian flavors. )

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved by installing from source.

First download source code from Node.js website and in command line execute this:

```
./configure make
make
install
```

You'll need `make` and a C-compiler, for example `gcc`.

Comment: You mean compiling? Your answer is vague.

Comment: Yeah, I compile from source on GitHub.

Comment: Care to expand your answer? So that it is more useful for everybody?

Comment: Sure. You can download source code from [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/download/) web-site and in command line execute this: `./configure make, make, install`. Plese separate ',' with new line.

Comment: I mean, edit your own answer. It's expected of you by StackOverflow.